Mobile browsers change page view when keyboard is open
I have a simple chat application which works as a webpage and it consists of mainly 3 parts (header, main, footer).
Page layout is same as whatsapp. Header and footer always on the screen and messages on main div with overflow-y: scroll property. So you can scroll up and down to see messages in main div also interact with header and footer buttons for remaining purposes.
I build website layout with flexbox rules and everything was working fine until last few mobile browser updates on Samsung Internet and Google Chrome. Possibly including other mobile browsers as well now.
Problems listed below and I want to clarify that this problems only occur in mobile browser when user touches to an input for typing. So when mobile keyboard opens browsers stop listening CSS rules. On desktop everything works as expected.
I am aware of that opening and closing mobile keyboard changes window.innerHeight. I can listen for window resize event to do some hacky stuff but this is not I really want. This should be fixed with CSS rules.
Problems listed below:

Page moves slightly upwards when mobile keyboard is open (Image-1)
Header div disappears when mobile keyboard is open (Image-1)
Footer div goes under the when mobile keyboard is open (Image-2)
Footer div slightly appears when typing (Image-3)

Screenshots:



Code example with grid layout


  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 60px;
  }
  .header {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  .main {
    background-color: moccasin;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  .footer {
    background-color: tomato;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .input {
    background-color: white;
  }
  .main p {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lime;
  }
<div class="header">
  Header
</div>

<div class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="input" contenteditable="true">Content editable div</div>
</div>



Change Grid rules with Flex rules you will get similar results.
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 60px;

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;

I also made some examples by using position: fixed; and position: sticky; properties but result didn't really change.

Not a direct answer to your question, but you might find this page: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior interesting/helpful in some ways. It goes over a change they suddenly decided to make with how the keyboard overlay is handled. There's also some useful information about what to expect on different platforms. And then also the different viewport information/settings you have access to, which may help you decide how you want to manage this. Note the "Opting in to a different behavior" part, especially, in case that helps!
